# How to save a file name in the MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have developed this code below to the user upload a file and save the name of this file in the database, to be able to access it later, the upload is done normally, it goes to the designated folder, but the name is not saved in the database, does anyone know what's wrong with the code? Especially below the move_uploaded_file, because so far it works, then it goes wrong.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
$arq = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

$arq = str_replace(" ", "_", $arq);
$arq = str_replace("ç", "c", $arq);

if (file_exists("uploads/$arq")) {
  $a = 1;

  while (file_exists("uploads/[$a]$arq")) {
    $a++;
  }

  $arq = "[".$a."]".$arq;
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$arq)) {
  $objDb = new db();
  $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
  $sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('$email', '$arq')";
  if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo 'Plano de aula 1 enviado com sucesso!';
  } else {
    echo (mysqli_error($link));
    echo 'Erro ao enviar o plano de aula!';
  }

} else {
  echo "Nenhum arquivo selecionado!";
}

}
?>
```

That is the code used to connect with the database:

```
class db {
//host
private $host = 'localhost';

//usuario
private $usuario = '111111';

//senha
private $senha = '11111111';

//banco de dados
private $database = 'dsfadsfasd';

public function conecta_mysql(){

//criar a conexão
$con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->database);

//ajustar a charser de cominicação entre a aplicação e o bd
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

//verificar se houve erro de conexão
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Erro ao tentar se conectar com o banco de dados'.mysqli_connect_error();
}

return $con;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @usmanikram I'm storing the file name at  ***$sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('$email', '$arq')";***  line 16!

Comment: is $arq correct? assuming nomearq is the file name. You susceptible to SQL injection http://bobby-tables.com/ . Also phpMyAdmin is just an interface for mysql. Not a database it self.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira try this: $sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('" . $email . "', '" . $arq ."')";

Comment: @usmanikram even this way doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please print the query and show it to me?

Comment: @usmanikram How can i send images here?

Comment: @ArthurOliveira, i just want to see the query. use echo $sql; to print the query

Comment: The host i'm using set 2 hours until i can upload files again, so i have to wait to print the query, As soon as i can i will send here to you!

Comment: @usmanikram This is the query ***insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('arthurso93@gmail.com', [1]index.php)***. Also, after i solve some mistakes i made, like forgot to include the database it shows that message: ***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[1]index.php)' at line 1***

Comment: What are the errors you are getting ?

Comment: @usmanikram Thank you so much man, the code is working just fine now, i will put the final code here to people who might look foward to solve this problem.

Comment: @BRjava It was some errors in the writting of the code, I used '$something' where i was suppose to use ".$something.". Thank you very much man!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't have the privilege to comment right now but shouldn't this be like this plus you don't have a semicolon at the end of your sql script

```
$sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('" . $email . "', '" 
 .$arq . "');";
```

and also this

```
if (file_exists("uploads/" . $arq)) {
  $a = 1;

  while (file_exists("uploads/". $a . ".". $arq)) {
    $a++;
  }

  $arq = $a.".".$arq;
}
```

with a full stop between your file number and name

Comment: How are you including the db class file

Comment: @ArthurOliveira i don't see anywhere you assign a value to the $email variable

Comment: @ArthurOliveira plus you also don't have a semicolon at the end of your sql script

Comment: I'm using ***require_once('conecta.php');***, but i forgot to put this, and the variable $email i'm using a session to save the login data! I'll try again including the db class file, but i have to wait 2 hours to do that, because i use a free host.

Comment: I solve those mistakes and now it shows that message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[1]index.php)' at line 1

Comment: Please use prepared statements to insert data.

Comment: @RichardMuvirimi Itried and it works just fine, what is the difference about using ".$something." or using '$something"?