# Pushing Attachment Path to DB table

Tags: php, html, mysqli, attachment

I've updated my project to it's almost final form and made a small change. The suggestion of @Raghbendra Nayak worked before the change and now, I'm trying to incorporate it to my new form. After 'submit' it pushes the item to the folder still and the link to the DB, however the link is on a separate row and not on the same row where the data name-description written is found.

Update: Got it working guys. Thanks!

Comment: In general context we use a specific folder to save files. So you know the where file going to be stored. just store name of file into database. While showing just append name with fixed file folder path. It's gonna work.

Comment: [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) is for creating a database connection, not for making queries. I would recommend that [you checkout the examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php).

Comment: Hello @amku91 - do you have a sample reference that I can look at? I'm kinda new with this. Thanks!

Comment: @David Sure. you can go. through this stack post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896627/how-to-save-a-file-name-in-the-mysql-database. Here user using upload folder. Tell me if this gonna help or not?

Comment: @David: Check my answer and try,hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hello @Raghbendra Nayak - I've updated the content and incorporating your suggestion. It works before prior to the change I made and I'm trying to link the statements so it will produce one 'id' for all the data and link.

Comment: @David: Still facing problem?

Comment: @Raghbendra Nayak - Sort of, as I need to merge if with my new form (please see updated post above). Running it as is, results to, file being uploaded to the folder (correct) and the link to a separate row (incorrect), it should be on the same table row with the $name and $description.

Comment: Hello @amku91 - I'm almost there. I just need to figure out why it is posting on a separate row wherein I've included it in the form. I guess I'm missing something or doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply follow the below code to insert data in database why you are using `mysqli_connect` to run the insert query.

**Updated:**

**Change your if condition:**

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$upload_directory.$path)){

    mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "order") or die ("Connecting to DB failed");

    mysqli_connect("INSERT INTO item VALUES ('', '$path')");

}
```

**To**

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],$upload_directory.$path)){

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "order") or die ("Connecting to DB failed");
    // If you want to save image name you can get like below:
    $filename = $_FILES["filename"]["name"];
    $path = $path."/".$filename;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO item (path) VALUES ('$path')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}
```

You have to add your image name also. Hope it will work for you, let me know it anything required.

Comment: I've updated the content and incorporating your suggestion. It works before prior to the change I made and I'm trying to link the statements so it will produce one 'id' for all the data and link.